# In DolphinDB, how to group a table by value of a certain column to achieve the same operation as qcut in pandas?

Tags: pandas, grouping, dolphindb

testData = table(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 as `id,1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 as` val)

Divide val column into 2 groups: val<=5, 5<val<=10, and then obtain the sum of each group.

Comment: sum of which variable?

Comment: should be sum of val column

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
testData = table(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 as id,1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 as val)
select sum(val) from testData group by val <= 5
```